# Visualforce: Display link to a document in the Documents folder.

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am trying to display a link on a custom VF page to a word document which has been uploaded to a folder in the Documents tab.

For some reason this is not working as expected. The link is not pointing to the document. 
Security is also not an issue. I am not doing something right in the VF I suppose.

Here is my controller code:

```
public with sharing class osv_portal_HomePageContoller {
public string strDocUrl;
public osv_portal_HomePageContoller()

{

    try
    {
        List<Document> lstDocument = [Select Name from Document where Name = 'SLA-Technology' limit 1];
        string strOrgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
        strDocUrl = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+lstDocument[0].Id;

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error in getDocumentLogoUrl() ' + e.getMessage()));
        System.debug('Error: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
        System.debug('The URL is ' + strDocUrl);
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'The URL returned is ' + strDocUrl));   

    }
```

}

This is my VF code:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!strDocUrl}" id="theLink" styleclass="slabutton">
    <span class="delete">Service Level Agreement</span>
 </apex:outputLink>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue is that you're referencing `1stDocument[0].Id` but not pulling `Id` in your query.  Also, as a rule, you should not start variables with numbers.

### Try changing the above code to this:

```
public with sharing class osv_portal_HomePageContoller {
public string strDocUrl;
public osv_portal_HomePageContoller()

{

  try
  {
    List<Document> FirstDocument = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Document WHERE Name = 'SLA-Technology' LIMIT 1];
    string strOrgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
    strDocUrl = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+FirstDocument[0].Id;

  }
  catch (Exception e) 
  {
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error in getDocumentLogoUrl() ' + e.getMessage()));
    System.debug('Error: ' + e.getMessage());
  }
    System.debug('The URL is ' + strDocUrl);
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'The URL returned is ' + strDocUrl));   

  }
}
```

Comment: I had id in the SOQL query before. That is not the issue I think.

Comment: Sorry, I was just going off of the code you provided.  Have you tried changing the variable to one which doesn't start with an integer?

Comment: Hmm..I didnt get what you're saying. This is my variable name 'strDocUrl '

Comment: The thing is when you hover over the link in the VF page, it does not show anything related to /servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=..Instead it shows a link back to the page itself. The SOQL query works fine and returns the ID correctly. I have no clue so far as to what could be wrong.

Comment: I was referring to your variable `lstDocument[0].Id` which starts with a 1.  But if no link is showing, I feel like it might have to do with you not choosing the controller.  Are you specifying the correct controller for this link within your VF page?

Comment: Yes I have. The VF page will give an error if the variable being referenced is not present in the controller.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think I can assist much further without the full code for your controller and VF page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17191/discussion-between-victorkilo-and-richard-n)

Comment: My VF page is very large. I think the code is fine and I am having this issue because of the user license which is "High volume portal users". This person must also have been affected by the same. http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Force-com-Sites/Documents-and-High-Volume-Customer-Portal-users/m-p/500759#M6569

Comment: I have now confirmed this issue is because of the license of the user "High volume portal users" and security settings on the documents. These users cannot work with sharing rules and I would need to make that document public which I cannot do. Therefore I will use Attachments on custom objects to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

> public string strDocUrl;

to

> public string strDocUrl{get;set;}